# How do you approximate a shape with fixed angle polygon in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have some contours for example the three colored shapes in this image.

[image]

I would like to approximate the boundary of each with a polygon **WITH** the constraint that the interior angles of the polygon are some fixed values. So the angle should snap to say {45 or 90} degrees and also ensure no edge is less that a certain number of pixels .e.g 50 - so there aren't many tiny edges. So the result for the green contour would be:

[image]

Is this possible in OpenCV?

Comment: Is it also a constraint that all the edges be parallel to either the X-axis or the Y-axis?

Comment: what would you like the minimum side length to be (otherwise we could end up just doing anti-aliasing)?

Comment: @idontknow no that is not a constraint.

Comment: @IanChu Yes there is a minimize side length impose e.g. 50 pixels I'll edit that in.